# How to create Table with Module name Prefixed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008r2-express

I downloaded AdentureWorks Database and found a new style to create a table like below.

1. Sales.SalesOrderHeader
2. Person.Person
3. Sales.SalesOrderDetail

Can you explain how to create table which can have a module prefix ?

Please let me know if you have any confusion in the query...

Comment: They are *schema* names, take a look at - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190387(v=sql.105).aspx - http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/07/sql-server-importance-of-database-schemas-in-sql-server/

Comment: @AlexK - Can you share any Video Tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Videos you can find here:  [one](http://vimeo.com/3098935), [two](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XMigeEc0vg),[three](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6cYP6Yf68As)

Answer (score 0):

You can Change your schema as per your given module name.

Schema name = `Sales` in `SalesOrderHeader` and `SalesOrderDetail` Table

and when you are accessing table at that time write `Sales.SalesOrderHeader`

By default Schema name is `dbo`